# How to get critical css from multiple external URLs?

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, gulp

I currently have the following gulpfile.js that fetches the critical css from a couple URLs and creates 2 separate files:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var purge = require('gulp-css-purge');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var critical = require('critical');

gulp.task('critical', ['generate'], function () {
    gulp.src(['./css/critical-*.css'])
        .pipe(concatCss('./css/critical.css'))
        .pipe(purge())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

gulp.task('generate', function () {
    critical.generate({
        base: './',
        src: 'http://example.com/category.html',
        dimensions: [{
            width: 1280,
            height: 960
        }],
        dest: 'css/critical-category.css',
        minify: true,
        extract: false,
        pathPrefix: '/css',
        ignore: ['font-face']
    });

    critical.generate({
        base: './',
        src: 'http://example.com/',
        dimensions: [{
            width: 1280,
            height: 960
        }],
        dest: 'css/critical-home.css',
        minify: true,
        extract: false,
        pathPrefix: '/css',
        ignore: ['font-face']
    });
});
```

The only reason I'm creating the `critical-*.css` files is to later concatenate them and remove duplicate content into a single `critical.css` file.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I've been trying to use the generated critical css as part of a stream like on the critical [README](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical#gulp) but I haven't been able to get it to work using external URLs.